# Crash on Random Color Change

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, nsmutablearray

```
+ (UIColor *)randomColor
{
     static NSMutableArray * __colors;
     if (__colors == nil) {
         __colors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],
                        [UIColor orangeColor],
                        [UIColor yellowColor],
                        [UIColor blueColor],
                        [UIColor greenColor],
                        [UIColor purpleColor], nil];

     }
     static NSInteger index = 0;

     UIColor *color = __colors[index];
     index = index < 5 ? index + 1 : 0;
     return color;
}
```

In my app I have a button that is calling this to randomly change it's background color.

Once it cycles through the colors it crashes with this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Any advice on how to adjust my code to fix this issue?

EDIT:

I'm using a timer to cycle through the colors. Here's that if it helps:

```
- (void)startCountdown
{
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(advanceTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)advanceTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor randomColor];
}
```

EDIT:

The above method is the one I am using now.

It's working great so far, but one thing I'd like to add to is this:

On one view I may have multiple buttons or images that will have background's changing colors.

Right now I have 3 on the view.  Only 2 of them are changing but not cycling through all the colors, meaning 2 only get 3 colors each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cycle through the colours, you can use a `static integer` as an index.

```
+ (UIColor *)randomColor
{

    static NSMutableArray * __colors;
    if (__colors == nil) {
        __colors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],
                    [UIColor orangeColor],
                    [UIColor yellowColor],
                    [UIColor blueColor],
                    [UIColor greenColor],
                    [UIColor purpleColor], nil];

    }
    static NSInteger index = 0;

    UIColor *color = __colors[index];
    index = index < 5 ? index + 1 : 0;
    return color;
}
```

Comment: This helps, thanks! I do see one thing that is interesting. I will have multiple buttons with changing background colors. Right now I have 2 wired up. Each one is only getting 3 colors. I'd like each to rotate through however many colors I add in my array and not have it divided. Why are my colors being split up between my buttons and each not getting all of them?

Comment: You could use `__colors[(index++)%__colors.count]`, however this doesn't look like what he wanted, he wanted random colors, not sequential colors, and a full cycle before before getting new random colors.

Answer (score 2):

Once your colors run out your array is empty, and index 0 is beyond the array range of values.

Comment: so how do I get it to loop this?

Comment: You could check if the array count is zero and then re-create it, but you may want to find more efficient ways - delete/create are quite expensive.

Comment: From what I gather, you want random colors, but a full loop of colors before getting a new color. I would create a static C array of unique indexes, and iterate it with a static integer. Once the iteration is done (index == count), I would fill it with new random values and set the static index to zero.

Comment: Come to think of it, and easier approach would be to use a single mutable array, and a static index (`static NSInteger i = 0;`), start by shuffling the array, and then loop until `i==__colors.count` and then reset the index (or use mod) and reshuffle the array.